# How do I use multiple cells in a tableView using Rx?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, rx-swift

I have a `tableView` with two `cells`: `StaticSupportTableViewCell` and `SupportTableViewCell`. As the name suggests the first `cell` is a single static cell on top of the `tableView`. `SupportTableViewCell` can be any number and should be displayed underneath the static `cell`.

I have code that `binds` and returns the correct `cell`:

```
viewModel.multiContent.bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { tableView, index, item in
    if let cellViewModel = item as? StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StaticSupportTableViewCell.identifier) as? StaticSupportTableViewCell
        cell?.viewModel = cellViewModel
        guard let guardedCell = cell else { return UITableViewCell()}
        return guardedCell
}
    if let cellViewModel = item as? SupportTableViewCellViewModel {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SupportTableViewCell.identifier) as? SupportTableViewCell
        cell?.viewModel = cellViewModel
        guard let guardedCell = cell else { return UITableViewCell()}
        return guardedCell
    }
    else { return UITableViewCell() }
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In the `viewModel` I have the `multiContent` variable:

```
var multiContent = BehaviorRelay<[Any]>(value: [])
```

Now if I accept the `cell` `viewModels` onto that relay one by one it works:

This works:
`multiContent.accept([StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel(myString: "TESTING")])`

Or doing this instead:
`multiContent.accept(mainService.serviceProviders.compactMap { SupportTableViewCellViewModel(serviceProvider: $0, emailRelay: emailRelay)})`

But if I try both at the same time...

```
multiContent.accept([StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel(myString: "TESTING")])
        multiContent.accept(mainService.serviceProviders.compactMap { SupportTableViewCellViewModel(serviceProvider: $0, emailRelay: emailRelay)})
```

...only the last cell is shown. It's like the last one replaces the first one instead of being an addition to it.

So how do I accept both `cell` `viewModels` to the relay so that both are displayed in the `tableView`?

***EDIT***
I sort of got it right by adding the two `cell` `viewModels` into one `array`:

```
let contents: [Any] = [StaticSupportTableViewCellViewModel(brand: name, url: web.localized(), phoneNumber: phone.localized()), mainService.serviceProviders.compactMap { SupportTableViewCellViewModel(serviceProvider: $0, emailRelay: emailRelay)}]
```

And changed the `binding`:

```
if let cellViewModels = item as? [SupportTableViewCellViewModel] {...
```

This is problematic though as I'm stuck with and `array` of `[SupportTableViewCellViewModel]`. It doesn't work looping them and returning the `cells` as they overwrite one another.

The solution is to send in the `cell` `viewModel` `SupportTableViewCellViewModel` instead of `[SupportTableViewCellViewModel]`, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A BehaviorRelay only emits the most recent array accepted. When you call `accept(_:)` you aren't adding to the state of the relay, you are replacing its state. To emit both, you will need to concatenate the two arrays.

In general, you should avoid using Relays and Subjects in production code. They are good for learning the Rx system and samples but are hard to get right in real world situations. You only need them when converting non-Rx code into Rx or when setting up a feedback loop.

Also, a Subject, Relay or Observable shouldn't be a `var`. You don't want to replace one once setup. Make them `let`s instead.

Comment: Ah, yes, I tried adding them togeather in a single array and it.. halfway worked. See edit.

Comment: In the `items` closure, the `item` is a single item in the array, not the entire array. I personally would wrap the two types in an enum instead of using down-casting.